# How to replace "" to " by using JSON.Parser from scratch

Tags: javascript, json

I read an article about JSON.Parser from scratch by Tan Li Hau.
https://lihautan.com/json-parser-with-javascript/

And I want to custom his JSON.Parser which can replace `""` to `"` or `"""` to `"`. I mean if `"` keep more than 1 continuously, replace to `"` .

ex)

```
'{"n": ""aaa, should, ""}'
```

to

```
'{"n": "aaa, should, "}'
```

But for now, there is a syntax error of course.

I found the parseString() loops while `"` comes next. So I tried to update parseString() to replace `""` to `"` if it's continuously. But it's not working. Also It's not supported more than 1 `"`.
So if you could give me some advise, it would be helpful.

```
function fakeParseJSON(str) {
  let i = 0;

  const value = parseValue();
  expectEndOfInput();
  return value;

  function parseObject() {
    if (str[i] === "{") {
      i++;
      skipWhitespace();

      const result = {};

      let initial = true;
      // if it is not '}',
      // we take the path of string -> whitespace -> ':' -> value -> ...
      while (i < str.length && str[i] !== "}") {
        if (!initial) {
          eatComma();
          skipWhitespace();
        }
        const key = parseString();
        if (key === undefined) {
          expectObjectKey();
        }
        skipWhitespace();
        eatColon();
        const value = parseValue();
        result[key] = value;
        initial = false;
      }
      expectNotEndOfInput("}");
      // move to the next character of '}'
      i++;

      return result;
    }
  }

  function parseArray() {
    if (str[i] === "[") {
      i++;
      skipWhitespace();

      const result = [];
      let initial = true;
      while (i < str.length && str[i] !== "]") {
        if (!initial) {
          eatComma();
        }
        const value = parseValue();
        result.push(value);
        initial = false;
      }
      expectNotEndOfInput("]");
      // move to the next character of ']'
      i++;
      return result;
    }
  }

  function parseValue() {
    skipWhitespace();
    const value =
      parseString() ??
      parseNumber() ??
      parseObject() ??
      parseArray() ??
      parseKeyword("true", true) ??
      parseKeyword("false", false) ??
      parseKeyword("null", null);
    skipWhitespace();
    return value;
  }

  function parseKeyword(name, value) {
    if (str.slice(i, i + name.length) === name) {
      i += name.length;
      return value;
    }
  }

  function skipWhitespace() {
    while (
      str[i] === " " ||
      str[i] === "\n" ||
      str[i] === "\t" ||
      str[i] === "\r"
    ) {
      i++;
    }
  }

  function parseString() {
    if (str[i] === '"') {
      i++;
      let result = "";
      if (str[i - 1] + str[i] === '""') {
        (str[i - 1] + str[i]).replace('""', '"');
      }
      while (i < str.length && str[i] !== '"') {
        if (str[i] === "\\") {
          const char = str[i + 1];
          if (
            char === '"' ||
            char === "\\" ||
            char === "/" ||
            char === "b" ||
            char === "f" ||
            char === "n" ||
            char === "r" ||
            char === "t"
          ) {
            result += char;
            i++;
          } else if (char === "u") {
            if (
              isHexadecimal(str[i + 2]) &&
              isHexadecimal(str[i + 3]) &&
              isHexadecimal(str[i + 4]) &&
              isHexadecimal(str[i + 5])
            ) {
              result += String.fromCharCode(
                parseInt(str.slice(i + 2, i + 6), 16)
              );
              i += 5;
            } else {
              i += 2;
              expectEscapeUnicode(result);
            }
          } else {
            expectEscapeCharacter(result);
          }
        } else {
          result += str[i];
        }
        i++;
      }
      expectNotEndOfInput('"');
      i++;
      return result;
    }
  }

  function isHexadecimal(char) {
    return (
      (char >= "0" && char <= "9") ||
      (char.toLowerCase() >= "a" && char.toLowerCase() <= "f")
    );
  }

  function parseNumber() {
    let start = i;
    if (str[i] === "-") {
      i++;
      expectDigit(str.slice(start, i));
    }
    if (str[i] === "0") {
      i++;
    } else if (str[i] >= "1" && str[i] <= "9") {
      i++;
      while (str[i] >= "0" && str[i] <= "9") {
        i++;
      }
    }

    if (str[i] === ".") {
      i++;
      expectDigit(str.slice(start, i));
      while (str[i] >= "0" && str[i] <= "9") {
        i++;
      }
    }
    if (str[i] === "e" || str[i] === "E") {
      i++;
      if (str[i] === "-" || str[i] === "+") {
        i++;
      }
      expectDigit(str.slice(start, i));
      while (str[i] >= "0" && str[i] <= "9") {
        i++;
      }
    }
    if (i > start) {
      return Number(str.slice(start, i));
    }
  }

  function eatComma() {
    expectCharacter(",");
    i++;
  }

  function eatColon() {
    expectCharacter(":");
    i++;
  }

  // error handling
  function expectNotEndOfInput(expected) {
    if (i === str.length) {
      printCodeSnippet(`Expecting a \`${expected}\` here`);
      throw new Error("JSON_ERROR_0001 Unexpected End of Input");
    }
  }

  function expectEndOfInput() {
    if (i < str.length) {
      printCodeSnippet("Expecting to end here");
      throw new Error("JSON_ERROR_0002 Expected End of Input");
    }
  }

  function expectObjectKey() {
    printCodeSnippet(`Expecting object key here

For example:
{ "foo": "bar" }
  ^^^^^`);
    throw new Error("JSON_ERROR_0003 Expecting JSON Key");
  }

  function expectCharacter(expected) {
    if (str[i] !== expected) {
      printCodeSnippet(`Expecting a \`${expected}\` here`);
      throw new Error("JSON_ERROR_0004 Unexpected token");
    }
  }

  function expectDigit(numSoFar) {
    if (!(str[i] >= "0" && str[i] <= "9")) {
      printCodeSnippet(`JSON_ERROR_0005 Expecting a digit here

For example:
${numSoFar}5
${" ".repeat(numSoFar.length)}^`);
      throw new Error("JSON_ERROR_0006 Expecting a digit");
    }
  }

  function expectEscapeCharacter(strSoFar) {
    printCodeSnippet(`JSON_ERROR_0007 Expecting escape character

For example:
"${strSoFar}\\n"
${" ".repeat(strSoFar.length + 1)}^^
List of escape characters are: \\", \\\\, \\/, \\b, \\f, \\n, \\r, \\t, \\u`);
    throw new Error("JSON_ERROR_0008 Expecting an escape character");
  }

  function expectEscapeUnicode(strSoFar) {
    printCodeSnippet(`Expect escape unicode

For example:
"${strSoFar}\\u0123
${" ".repeat(strSoFar.length + 1)}^^^^^^`);
    throw new Error("JSON_ERROR_0009 Expecting an escape unicode");
  }

  function printCodeSnippet(message) {
    const from = Math.max(0, i - 10);
    const trimmed = from > 0;
    const padding = (trimmed ? 4 : 0) + (i - from);
    const snippet = [
      (trimmed ? "... " : "") + str.slice(from, i + 1),
      " ".repeat(padding) + "^",
      " ".repeat(padding) + message
    ].join("\n");
    console.log(snippet);
  }
}

console.log(`${fakeParseJSON('{"n": ""string, should, ""}')}`);
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/json-parser-with-error-handling-forked-9zetnc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You seem to be asking it to parse invalid JSON.  How would you distinguish a zero length string (`""`) to a second quote at the start of a string?  Also, the lines you seem to have inserted are not respecting potential index underflow and comparing a single character (`str[i]`) with a double quote sequence (which can't ever succeed).  `String.prototype.replace` returns a new string, and its operating on a temporary string constructed from the input.

Comment: Yes. I want to make the invalid json to valid. Oh yeah that's also the problem zero length string...

Comment: I suggest that you define how you want to 'repair' the input, as you need a strategy for determining how to allow the parser to recover, then attempt to implement a solution.  You might need to look ahead to decide if its reasonable to replace double quotes with single, especially as double quotes is valid in the case of zero length string.  I'd avoid actually manipulating the input string if you do, the code is effectively 'state' driven and you need to define a state for invalid strings.  I'm questioning why you actually want to do this, as file formats are valid/invalid for good reason.